# numeric to character date conversion sas

Tags: sas

This might be something really silly. But I am not able to figure out why this errors out.

Please help.

```
data _null_;
dt = date();
year = put(year(dt),4.);
curr_month = put(month(dt),2.);
call symput('year',year);
call symput('curr_mon',curr_month);
run;
put &year;
put &curr_mon;
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a ***specific problem or error*** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions *without a clear problem statement* are *not useful* to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without including your error and having run your code on my machine, I can only assume it's that you used 'put' and not %put.

Assuming the output should be that &year = 2016 and &curr_mon = 12